# FactoryGirl: How To Set Trait to True

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, faker

I have created a factory for my Request model. This model has a Boolean value that defaults to "false" at the database level. I have created a factory called `:fulfilled_request` that uses the **trait** feature in FactoryGirl, but, even though it is being called, the Request instance created has a `is_fulfilled` attribute of `false`. Any ideas? Below is my factory:

```
  factory :request do
    content { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
    association :requester
    association :group

    trait :has_neighbor do
      association :responder
    end

    trait :is_fulfilled do
      is_fulfilled true
    end

    trait :created_one_day_ago do
      created_at { 1.day.ago }
    end

    factory :request_with_neighbor, traits: [:has_neighbor]
    factory :fulfilled_request , traits: [:has_neighbor, :is_fulfilled]
    factory :day_old_request, traits: [:created_one_day_ago]
  end
```

Comment: You mean that this: `FactoryGirl.create(:fulfilled_request).is_fulfilled` returns false for you? Or there is some other logic involved?

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the factory in your spec? Also is your column on your model called `is_fulfilled` or just `fulfilled`.

Answer (score 0):

Call your factory like this.

```
FactoryGirl.create(:request, :is_fulfilled)
```

This will use the trait as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the reason that this was not working was that there was a `after_create` callback in the model that set `is_fulfilled` attribute to `false`.

This was done to mirror the database constraints in the model. I *think* this is one of those rare times when it doesn't make sense to mirror the database constraints in the model. The database is set to default this attribute to false. (The database therefore should **not** have a NOT NULL constraint either).

I'm just posting this for full documentation and to help others who might have this problem. Check your callbacks!

P.S. Thanks to **sikachu** on *#thoughtbot (irc)* for helping me spot that.